# Can I use polymorphism/inheritance in C# DocumentDb driver

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, polymorphism, azure-cosmosdb

I have a custom form object structure I use successfully with mongodb.

I've been investigating the possibility of replacing Mongo with DocumentDb.

My Class structure consists of a base control that different types of control inherit from. e.g. Textbox control, Dropdown Control

In mongo I use the discriminator field to store the actual type, in the c# DocumentDb driver I cant see find the same feature.

below is a sample of how mongo stores my class structure.

```
{
  "_t" : "TextboxControl",
  "LabelText" : "Location of incident",
  "IsRequired" : true,
  "_id" : "cbe059d9-b6a9-4de2-b63b-14d44b022e37"
}
```

In documentdb the structure looks like

```
{
  "LabelText": "Location of incident",
  "IsRequired": true,
  "id": "cbe059d9-b6a9-4de2-b63b-14d44b022e37"
}
```

As you can see the mongo version has a "_t" property stating the actual type, this is then used when I read the data to create the correct type. In the documentdb version it is simply a fieldtype

Comment: Proper support for JsonSerializerSettings is finally being worked on by MS: https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/issues/229

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After many weeks of searching I eventually came across the answer

https://github.com/markrexwinkel/azure-docdb-linq-extension

Basically this library extends the DocumentDb's C# SDK and allows for custom JSON settings to be applied. Under the hood the documentdb driver users json.net.

I now get the property "$type" which is a feature built into newtonsoft's excellent json.net library.

My json now looks like

```
{
  "$type" : "MyNameSpace.DropDownSingleFormBuilderControlTemplate, MyLibrary",
  "LabelText" : "Label Text"
  "IsRequired" : true,
  "_id" : "cbe059d9-b6a9-4de2-b63b-14d44b022e37"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think they added support for jsonserializer. You can add it via the 
**RequestOptions, TypeNameHandling.All**

```
var s =  new RequestOptions(){ JsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All }}
var result = await Client.CreateDocumentAsync(CollectionUri, @event2, s);
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you actually need to do this at all in DocumentDb.

You can assign the type as such:

```
private TextBoxControl GetControl(string link)
{
   return client.CreateDocumentQuery<TextBoxControl>(link, "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Controls");
}
```

My syntax might be out but the `CreateDocumentQuery<T>` part should do what you need without needing to store the type.

Comment: The would possibly work for some scenarios. But my specific setup I dont know the type, hence the type is stored in the json.